# $f:U(\mathbb{Z}/(n)) \to Aut(G)$, defined by $f([s]_n) = \phi_s$ is surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G = \left \langle {g} \right \rangle$ be a cyclic group of order $n \geq 2.$ Define a map  $\phi_s : G \to G (x \to x^s)$ and $Aut(G): = \{f:G \to G | f\ is\ isomorphism\}. $ Then, $\phi_s$ is an isomorphism iff $gcd(s,n)=1. $

Could anyone advise me on how to show the map $f:U(\mathbb{Z}/(n)) \to Aut(G)$, defined by $f([s]_n) = \phi_s$ is surjective? i.e. given $f \in Aut(G),$ how do I find $[s]_n \in U(\mathbb{Z}/(n))$ such that $f(g^i) = g^j = (gi)^s?$ Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f\in Aut(G)$, then $f(g) = g^s$ for some $s\in \mathbb{N}$. Then for any $x\in G$, there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x = g^k$, whence
$$
f(x) = f(g)^k = g^{sk} = x^s
$$
Hence, $f = \phi_s$

Answer (score 1):

Given $f$ in $Aut(G)$, the question is, what does it do with $g$, the generator of $G$? It must send it to some power of $g$, right? This will tell you what element of $U(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ you want.

(Since $f$ is an isomorphism, what it does with the generator $g$ will determine what it does with everything!)